# Родит или рОдит?

Tags: фонетика

Когда речь идет о плодородной почве, то она родит или рОдит?
Вопрос возник, когда я читал интересные ответы по поводу поговорки "мать сыра земля". Как-то к земле больше применимо (точнее, гармоничнее звучит) слово "родит" именно с ударением на О, но по правилам, вроде как, на И. Или же здесь такая же разница, как между словами "разлив" и "рОзлив" (тут еще и гласная меняется)?

Comment: Просто приставка РОЗ- всегда ударная

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: РодИТ. С ударением на О варианта нет. [Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.
Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/lop/)